# angularjs filter multidimensional object json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I wnt to use ng-repeat to display a list filtered by an object value. Here is a plukr of my attempt https://plnkr.co/edit/vD4UfzM4Qg7c0WGTeY18?p=preview

The following returns all of my JSON `names` as expected.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in collection_data">{{navitem.name}}</li>
```

now i want to filter and only show the names of the items that have `"foreign_lang": "es",` like in this json snippet

```
  {
    "id": "ddb06ba2-6348-4d45-9e63-a6fa3632e5c2",
    "created_at": "2015-10-12T18:34:15.668Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-04-14T15:55:37.433Z",
    "custom_attributes": {
      "Display Name": "Activos en Español",
      "foreign_lang": "es",
      "display_boxes": "false"
    },
  },
```

so i made this filter function

```
$scope.filterByDisplay = function() {
  $filter('filter')($scope.collection_data, ['foreign_lang', 'es']);
}
```

and called it like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in collection_data"  | filter: filterByDisplay>{{navitem.name}}</li>
```

I did not get any console errors but i got nothing returned.

How do I properly filter through this collection to only return items with `'foreign_lang', 'es'` as a value in the json? See the plunkr to see a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/vD4UfzM4Qg7c0WGTeY18?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering nested objects in ng-repeat with a search input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743724/filtering-nested-objects-in-ng-repeat-with-a-search-input-field)

Answer (score 2):

Third attempt (since the question was revised). Use the filter function to check each object individually, and returning only those that pass the truth test.

```
$scope.filterByDisplay = function(value) {
  return (value.content)
      && (value.content.custom_attributes) 
      && (value.content.custom_attributes.foreign_lang === "es");
}
```

[Updated Plunk - Using Filter Function](https://plnkr.co/edit/sMs0sb1qQvAUqjMoswuy?p=preview)